# Allow all files type except one in NSOpenPanel

Tags: macos, filter, nsopenpanel

my application create a "new" type (extension) of file, let say its ".newtype", so when i want to browse files with NSOpenPanel to create it, this type of files have to be not selectable.

how can i pass ALL files type except ".newtype" to the NSOpenPanel instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a delegate that handles the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate) `panel:shouldEnableURL:` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate/panel%3ashouldEnableURL%3a).

Comment: thank you this work like a charm. and to participate this is the code:
- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ([[((NSString*)[url absoluteString]) pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"newtype"])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}